# How to generate SKU id in MS SQL

Tags: sql-server

Can anyone tell me, how can we generate SKU like Ram-Me-123, Laptop-dell-1234578. This format should like Product name and Company or some specification and serial number

Comment: Do you heve a table to get data from and concat? if so, please post table structure, sample data, expected results as formatted text.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't provide a sample data to work on or anything else can help us to help you, but here is a simple example:

```
CREATE TABLE Products (
    SerialNumber VARCHAR(20),
    Name VARCHAR(20),
    CompanyName VARCHAR(20)
    );
INSERT INTO Products VALUES
('1234578', 'Laptop', 'Dell'),
('9512369', 'Laptop', 'Lenovo'),
('8547-H2', 'Phone', 'Sonny'),
('8787963', 'Phone', 'Condor');

SELECT *, Name+ '-' +CompanyName+ '-' +SerialNumber AS SKU
FROM Products;
```

Results:

```
+--------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+
| SerialNumber |  Name  | CompanyName |          SKU          |
+--------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+
| 1234578      | Laptop | Dell        | Laptop-Dell-1234578   |
| 9512369      | Laptop | Lenovo      | Laptop-Lenovo-9512369 |
| 8547-H2      | Phone  | Sonny       | Phone-Sonny-8547-H2   |
| 8787963      | Phone  | Condor      | Phone-Condor-8787963  |
+--------------+--------+-------------+-----------------------+
```